# jQuery is not defined, when importing unitegallery.min.js in typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript2.0

```
import * as jq from 'jquery';
import * as ugg from 'unitegallery/dist/js/unitegallery.min.js';
```

Error encountered:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

```
at eval (unitegallery.min.js:10)
at Object../node_modules/unitegallery/dist/js/unitegallery.min.js (vendor.bundle.js:757)
at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
at eval (app.component.ts:3)
at Object../src/app/app.component.ts (main.bundle.js:43)
at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
at eval (app.module.ts:6)
at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (main.bundle.js:51)
at __webpack_require__ (inline.bundle.js:55)
at eval (main.ts:4)
```

Comment: this suggest that both js did not find. so just f12 in browser, go to console, right click on js with new tab.

Comment: Try change `import * as jq from 'jquery';` to `import * as jQuery from 'jquery';`

Comment: I already changed it to jQuery but the error is still reproduce.

Comment: Is there anything I need to import?